# Java client-server increment and decrement client count

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

I'm trying to teach myself Java programming. Currently I am working on some client-server code. My objective is to increment the client count before the thread is launched, and decrement the count when the thread completes. Right now, the thread just sleeps for a few seconds. You can see the full directions here:

http://archive.oreilly.com/oreillyschool/courses/java5/Homework/Projects/serverEssentials_proj.project.html

Here is the code I currently have:

RepositoryServer.java

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RepositoryServer {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    int state = 0;

    public void bind() throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9172);
        state=1;
    }

    public void process() throws IOException {
        while (state ==1) {
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

            new RepositoryThread(client).start();
        }

        shutdown();
    }

    void shutdown() throws IOException {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            serverSocket.close();
            serverSocket=null;
            state=0;
        }
    }
}
```

RepositoryClient.java

```
package client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RepositoryClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 9172);

        PrintWriter toServer = new PrintWriter (server.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));

        for (int num=0; num<3; num++) {
            toServer.println("SIZE");
            if (!toServer.checkError()) {
                int response = Integer.valueOf(fromServer.readLine());
                String value = fromServer.readLine();
                if (response==0) {
                    System.out.println(num + ": Number of Images: "+ value);
                } else if (response==-1) {
                    System.err.println(value);
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Received unknown response: " +response);
                }
            }
        }

        server.close();
    }
}
```

RepositoryThread.java

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RepositoryThread extends Thread {
    Socket client;
    BufferedReader fromClient;
    PrintWriter toClient;

    RepositoryThread (Socket s) throws IOException {
        fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        toClient=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        client = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String request = fromClient.readLine();
                if (request == null) {
                    break;
                }

                if (request.equals("SIZE")) {
                    output("0");
                } else {
                    //internal server error. Try to continue and keep processing
                    outputError("Unable to process request: "+ request);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Thread processing terminated: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            fromClient.close();
            toClient.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Unable to close connection: " +ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    void output(String result) {
        toClient.println(0);
        toClient.println(result);
    }

    void outputError(String error) {
        toClient.println(-1);
        toClient.println(error);
    }
}
```

ServerLauncher.java

```
package server;

public class ServerLauncher {
    public static RepositoryServer create() throws Exception {
        RepositoryServer server = new RepositoryServer();
        server.bind();
        return server;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RepositoryServer server = create();

        System.out.println("Server awaiting client connections");
        server.process();
        System.out.println("Server shutting down.");
    }
}
```

TestServer.java

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import client.*;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestServer extends TestCase {
    static int clientCount =0;
    public void testMultipleClients() throws Exception {
        RepositoryServer server = launchServer();

        System.out.println(clientCount);
        launchClient();
        System.out.println(clientCount);
        launchClient();
        System.out.println(clientCount);
        launchClient();
        System.out.println(clientCount);

        //wait until everything done.
        //isClientCountZero();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        server.shutdown();
        assertEquals(0, server.state);
    }

    public static void launchClient() {
        //incrementClientCount();
        new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                try {

                    RepositoryClient.main(new String[]{});

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Unable to launch test client.");
                }
            }
        }.start();
        //decrementClientCount();
    }

    public static RepositoryServer launchServer() throws Exception {
        final RepositoryServer server = ServerLauncher.create();
        assertEquals(1, server.state);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    server.process();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.err.println("Server completed");
                }
            }
        }.start();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        return server;
    }

    public static synchronized boolean isClientCountZero(){
        if (clientCount==0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static synchronized void decrementClientCount(){
        clientCount--;
    }

    public static synchronized void incrementClientCount(){
        clientCount++;
    }
}
```

The code in question is in TestServer.java. When the Thread.sleep() methods are active, the server outputs text as expected. However, when the Thread.sleep() methods are commented out and replaced with the increment, decrement, and clientCount methods, it no longer outputs any text, just 'Server Completed'. What is my wrong with my solution to the posted link?

Thank you

Comment: You need some synchronization, or `volatile`. Curious assignment. Normally it is the server that keeps client counts. The statement 'whenever you have to insert sleep statements into your code, you know that you are very close to writing a "hack"' is incorrect. You *have* written a hack. Sleeps in networking code do not solve protocol problems.

Comment: So I've declared three synchronized methods in TestServer.java. If you uncomment them and comment the sleeps, it no longer outputs any text. Even if you move the methods calls to inside the try block within the run() method of the thread you will get the same issue.